# ClassCasteException in Websphere 8.5.5.2

Tags: class, jakarta-ee, exception, casting

I am getting classCasteException in below statement :

```
function axxxxx(X resource)
{
    ((SimpleConnectionImpl)resource).somefunction();// getting classcaste exception here
}
```

I inspected the runtime value of resource and found it to be `org.java.SimpleConnectionImpl@ao4d0323`. Still it is unable to typecaste.where as `SimpleConnectionImpl` is also in same package.

Do you have any suggestions? InstanceOff operator is also returning false here. When I am doing `getclass()` it is returning same class name.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two versions of the same JAR on the classpath. Be sure that only one version of the JAR containing SimpleConnectionImpl is in all of the dependencies that are included by all the JAR artifacts (EAR, WAR, etc) in the complete application.

More precisely, you want to have only one copy of any given class under a single classloader. Removing duplicates of classes for all your artifacts is an important part of deployment in J2EE environments and reduces errors like these, which can sometimes make it into production.

Comment: Thanks..I think this should be the reason . I will check this today.Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Sure! If you are using Maven in your build, you can typically resolve this by using ```<exclusion>``` elements in your dependency imports. So if A depends on B depends on C, you can put an exclusion of C in the ```<dependency>``` on B in A's POM, then C will only be a part of the packaging in B, which is probably closer to what you want.